# About symmetric and anti-symmetric states of a nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, spin-statistics

Ehrenfest and Oppenheimer published a paper [*Note on the Statistics of Nuclei*](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.37.333) in which they write:[image]

The "rule" mentioned in paragraph is also stated in the paper. It is:
[image]

I am unable to follow the argument leading to equation (1). In particular:

- If the degree of degeneracy is $g$ why would half the states be symmetric and the rest anti-symmetric? I would have expected all of them to be either symmetric or anti-symmetric.
- Assuming for the moment that indeed half of them are symmetric, how does one arrive at equation (1)?

I am tempted to believe that there is a combinatorial argument leading to (1) but I am unable to find one. Can someone please help?

**A note**: The paper was published in 1930 when the nucleus was thought to be made up of protons and electrons. A nucleus of mass number $A$ was supposed to have $A - Z$ electrons in it so that the net charge was $+Z$.

Comment: how is a nucleus built up from electrons and protons? Is this a pre-neutron treatment?

Comment: Yes, the neutron was not known in 1930. Kindly read neutron wherever electron appears.

Comment: I don't think you can just swap electron and neutron and get anything resembling reality. Broken symmetry notwithstanding, a proton is a neutron, they are two isospin projections of the $I=\frac 1 2$ _nucleon_ , which imposes symmetry conditions that do not apply to an $ep$ system.

Comment: @JEB, I understand your point. But we are discussing a paper published in 1930 when none of this was known. The question is about counting symmetric and antisymmetric states of a bunch of fermions. For the purpose of this question alone, we can mentally replace electron with neutron.

Comment: yeah, I didn't see that note in then end. Maybe lead with that? 2 non-identical fermions should be straightforward, ofc a nucleus is much smaller than the Compton wavelength of the electron (and this post Dirac eq., but pre positron...so a gray area), but by modern standards it doesn't work at all.